# How to give roughness, metallic and diffusion to a custom object in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, object, scenekit

I want to give diffusion, roughness and metallic to my custom object in SceneKit.

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "sunglasses.dae")!
material?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "BaseColor.png")
material?.roughness.contents = UIImage(named: "Roughness.png")
material?.metalness.contents = UIImage(named: "Metallic.png")
material?.normal.contents = UIImage(named: "Normal.png")
```

When I put sphere, instead of my custom dae file, then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the nodes of the scene object and then you can access the material of it and assign the different attributes like diffuse, normal etc.

```
 // create a new scene
 let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

 let planeNode = scene.rootNode.childNodes.first?.childNodes.first
 let material = planeNode?.geometry?.materials.first
 material?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
```

I hope it will help you.